# Django ModelChoiceField: filtering query set and setting default value as an object

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django Form class defined likes this in `Models`:

```
class AccountDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    adminuser = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

This works OK, but it has some limitations I can't seem to work around:

(1) I would like to use a filter on the queryset, based on a variable `accountid` passed to the form, like this:

```
User.objects.filter(account=accountid)
```

This can't work in the model because `accountid` can't be passed as a variable, of course.

It follows that the `queryset` must somehow be defined in the `Views`, but as far as I can see it's a required field in the Form class.

(2) I would like to make the default choice of `AccountDetailsForm` an object in the database, which I can select in the `Views` like this:

```
User.objects.filter(account=accountid).filter(primary_user=1)
```

I've tried specifying the adminuser as a default value in the form, (which works with other standard form fields, like `CharField`):

```
adminuser = User.objects.filter(account=accountid).filter(primary_user=1)

...

form = AccountDetailsForm({'adminuser': adminuser})
return render_to_response('accounts/edit/accountdetails.html', 
{'form': form, 'account':account})
```

But no luck.

Should I be using something other than `ModelChoiceField` given the flexibility I need here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Override the init method and accept a new keyword argument

```
class AccountDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    adminuser = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        accountid = kwargs.pop('accountid', None)
        super(AccountDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if accountid:
            self.fields['adminuser'].queryset = User.objects.filter(account=accountid)

form = AccountDetailsForm(accountid=3)
```

You can always just set the choices manually in the view as well.

```
form = AccountDetailsForm()
form.fields['adminuser'].queryset = User.objects.filter(account=accountid)
```

---

Be warned: you are *not* setting default values by passing in a dictionary to a form like in your example.

You are actually creating a Bound Form, potentially triggering validation and all that jazz.

To set defaults, [use the initials argument.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial)

```
form = AccountDetailsForm(initial={'adminuser':'3'})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Setting the queryset in the view worked well. The part I couldn't work out is setting the bound form value (rather than the default) of ModelChoiceField as _User.objects.filter(account=accountid).filter(primary_user=1)_. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can override the field in the view

```
yourForm = AccountDetailsForm()

yourForm.fields['accomodation'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(User.objects.filter(account=accountid).filter(primary_user=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that hasn't been mentioned here yet is the [Form.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.clean) method. This method is specifically for custom validation.

For your example, you could do something like this:

```
class AccountDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    adminuser = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    account_id = forms.IntegerField()  # or ModelChoiceField if that applies

    def clean(self):
        account_id = self.cleaned_data['account_id']
        self.cleaned_data['adminuser'] = User.objects.filter(account_id=account_id)

    return self.cleaned_data
```

The clean() method gets called after the default clean methods, so you can use self.cleaned_data (same as form.cleaned_data in the view) and return it however you'd like.

Even better, you can name the method according to the field you'd like to clean (`def clean_adminuser`) and make easier to read.

```
def clean_adminuser(self):
    account_id = self.cleaned_data['account_id']
    return User.objects.filter(account_id=account_id)
```

Also in this method you can call [Form.add_error()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) if there are any issues you want to handle.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2.0 you can pass object (`User` in your case) from the `view` to the `form` like this (you have to retrieve obj from the DB first):

```
form = AccountDetailsForm(initial={'adminuser': adminuser})
```

It will give you a default selected object (answers your 2) question)

Comment: @JonProgrammer in the form?

Comment: My current solution is that one here, but I feel it's not the most effective way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512606/django-forms-queryset