# Django CreateView filter foreign key in select field

Tags: django, django-views

I need some help with Django 2 and Python 3.

I'm using a `CreateView` to add new reccords in my database, but I need to make a filter for my `Aviso` form page to make the select field (field `turma`) to show only instances where the `representante` is the current user.

This is my model:

```
class Turma(models.Model):
    nome                    = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False, help_text='Obrigatório.')
    alunos                  = models.ManyToManyField(User, help_text='Obrigatório', related_name='alunos_matriculados')
    data_cadastro           = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    representante           = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False)
    colegio                 = models.ForeignKey(Colegio, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False, null=False, help_text='Obrigatório.')

class Aviso(models.Model):
    data_final              = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name="Data Final")
    comentarios             = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    ultima_modificacao      = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    data_post               = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    turma                   = models.ForeignKey(Turma, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    materia                 = models.ForeignKey(Materia, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
```

This is my view:

```
class AvisoCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):  #Cadastro de Aviso
    template_name = 'form.html'
    model = models.Aviso
    login_url = '/login/'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('visualizar_aviso')
    fields = [
        'turma',
        'materia',
        'tipo_aviso',
        'comentarios',
        'data_final'
    ]
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['titulo'] = 'Cadastrar aviso'
        context['input'] = 'Adicionar'
        return context
```

How could that be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a queryset to the ForeignKey field.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'].fields['turma'].queryset = Turma.objects.filter(representante=self.request.user)    
    context['titulo'] = 'Cadastrar aviso'
    context['input'] = 'Adicionar'
    return context
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) for that model.
And based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329761/9225671) you could override the forms `__init__()` method to alter the fields queryset.

```
class AvisoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Aviso
        fields = [
            'data_final', 'comentarios', 'ultima_modificacao', 'data_post',
            'turma', 'materia',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # restrict the queryset of 'Turma'
        self.fields['turma'].queryset = self.fields['turma'].queryset.filter(
            representante=user)
```

Then, in your view, replace the attribute `fields` with `form_class`:

```
class AvisoCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    ...
    form_class = AvisoForm
    ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Maybe you need to adjust a few things for your specific case.
Let us know if that solved it.

Comment: I got an error: "AvisoForm" object has no attribute 'request'.

Comment: @RafaelZottesso Ah, right, I edited my answer to include the method `AvisoCreateView.get_form_kwargs()` and I also added a line to `AvisoForm.__init__()`.

Comment: I made something like that and worked. Thank you for your time and response.