# Django: Forms Queryset

Tags: django

I wonder if that is the right approach. I first call `queryset=Reward.objects.all()` just to change it right after and filter it. However, I couldn't come up with a better solution. Do you have any thoughts on that?

```
   class ClaimRewardForm(forms.ModelForm):
        note = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
        title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Reward.objects.all())
        # note = forms.DropDown()

        class Meta:
            model = Reward
            fields = ['title']

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['title'].queryset = Reward.objects.filter(event=self.initial['event'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That queryset is never evaluated, because you always replace it on instantiation, so it doesn't really matter what you put there.

One alternative night be to use `Reward.objects.none()` to indicate that it's never used.

Answer (score 0):

If you should process set of models, try change your approach to FormSets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Briefly, FormSets approach seem so: 1. Declare ClaimRewardForm class for single model (`Reward` in your case) 2. Declare ClaimRewardFormSet for ClaimRewardForm with overriding

```
class BaseClaimRewardFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):

    """By default, when you create a formset from a model, the formset
    will use a queryset that includes all objects in the model"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'event' in kwargs.keys():
            event = kwargs.pop('event')
        else:
            event = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if event is not None:
            self.queryset = Reward.objects.filter(event=event)
        else:
            self.queryset = Reward.objects.none()


ClaimRewardFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(Reward, RewardForm, 
formset=BaseClaimRewardFormSet)
```