# Empty Django Form Select Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want empty `job_users` field before sending to the template. Because `job_groups` and `job_users` is dependent. I am calling ajax call when the group is select and users of that group will be displayed inside `job_users`. But now all users are displayed inside `job_users` select field.

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):

    job_description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':15}))
    job_users = None
    class Meta:
        model = Jobs
        fields = [  
                    'job_name', 
                    'job_group',
                    'job_users',
                ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_company = kwargs.pop('user_company', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['job_group'].queryset = None
```

`self.fields['job_group'].queryset = None` i am using this but it is giving me error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django ModelChoiceField: filtering query set and setting default value as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329586/django-modelchoicefield-filtering-query-set-and-setting-default-value-as-an-obj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    job_description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':15}))
    class Meta:
        model = Jobs
        fields = [  
                    'job_name', 
                    'job_group',
                ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_company = kwargs.pop('user_company', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['job_group'].queryset = Jobgroup.objects.none()
```

But, it will throw error when you try to validate the form using `form.is_valid()`. So before doing that, update the queryset in the views like this:

```
def some_view_def(request):
    form = JobForm(request.POST)
    form.fields['job_group'].queryset = JobGroup.objects.filter(...)  # <-- here 
    if form.is_valid():
       # rest of the code
```