# Filtering choices in a form based on previous field selection - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Just quickly to summarize I have an app, which allows clubs to sign up and carry out different tasks. One of the features is a scheduling / rosters. Currently I have a form to add times to the roster. The club pages work off a session key based on the initially selected club.

My form consists of:
club_id - which I have hidden and initialized based on the logged in user.
pitch_id - which is currently displaying all pitches associated to all clubs but I need this to only show pitches based on the foreign key for the club_id

Would appreciate any help.

form.py

```
from django import forms
from clubkit.roster.models import RosterId
import datetime
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class RosterForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta():
    model = RosterId
    fields = ('club_id', 'pitch_id', 'team_id', 'date',
              'start_time', 'finish_time', 'reoccuring_event',)
    widgets = {
        'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker'})
    }

    def clean_date(self):
        date = self.clean_date['date']
        if date < datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('Date cannot be in the past.'))
        return date

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RosterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['club_id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

models.py for pitch

```
class Pitch(models.Model):
club_id = models.ForeignKey(ClubInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pitches")
pitch_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
PITCH_SIZES = (
    ('S', 'Small'),
    ('M', 'Medium'),
    ('L', 'Large'),
)
PITCH_TYPE = (
    ('1', 'Outdoor'),
    ('2', 'Indoor'),
)
pitch_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PITCH_SIZES)
pitch_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PITCH_TYPE)
open_time = models.TimeField(default='09:00')
close_time = models.TimeField(default='22:00')
RENT_TYPE = (
    ('0', 'Not Available To Rent'),
    ('1', 'Available To Rent'),
)
rental = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RENT_TYPE)
rental_price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
max_people = models.IntegerField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.pitch_name
```

models.py for roster

```
from django.db import models
from clubkit.clubs.models import ClubInfo, Pitch, Team


# Model to store roster information
class RosterId(models.Model):
club_id = models.ForeignKey(ClubInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
pitch_id = models.ForeignKey(Pitch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date = models.DateField(max_length=8)
start_time = models.TimeField(default='')
finish_time = models.TimeField(default='')
reoccuring_event = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
class ClubRoster(APIView):
renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
template_name = 'roster.html'

# Get method to retrieve current roster information and form
def get(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        club_pk = request.session.get('pk')
        club_info = ClubInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
        reoccuring_event = RosterId.objects.filter(reoccuring_event=True, club_id=club_pk)
        inital_data = {
            'club_id': club_info,
        }
        form = RosterForm(initial=inital_data)
        roster = RosterId.objects.filter(club_id=club_pk)
        return Response({'form': form,
                         'roster': roster,
                         'club_pk': club_pk,
                         'reoccuring_event': reoccuring_event
                         })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I filter ForeignKey choices in a Django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for some manipulation of the form field query. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329761/8002464) will provide further help.

The result could look like this.

```py
from django import forms
from clubkit.roster.models import RosterId, Pitch
import datetime
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class RosterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = RosterId
        fields = ('club_id', 'pitch_id', 'team_id', 'date',
                  'start_time', 'finish_time', 'reoccuring_event',)
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker'})
        }

    def clean_date(self):
        date = self.clean_date['date']
        if date < datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('Date cannot be in the past.'))
        return date

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RosterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['club_id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        if instance:
            self.fields['pitch_id'].queryset = Roster.objects.filter(club_id=instance.club_id)
```

Ah well or adjust `instance` to your 'initial'.